# How to build Python Eggs for Android SL4A?

Tags: android, python, egg, sl4a

Does anyone have any tutorial on How I should go about building a Python Egg for installing it in my android phone ? I want to install the library - Hachoir (https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home) which parses files. The library is completely written in Python. I tried following these steps but in vain - http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/BuildingModules

Any help will be appreciated ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, make sure you have at least `r5` of SL4A, then you can grab a precompiled egg file from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-core), which you can finally install on the device by using the `Install Module` function in Python For Android.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Download that module as a zip file and extract its contents to a folder(it should have a setup.py normally). Open a command window there and type the following command:
`python setup.py bdist_egg`
The egg will be built in some time and will be saved in a folder named dist where the setup.py is located.
Copy this egg file to the download folder in your phone's memory or SD card and then you can install it using the 'install module' option in Python for Android app.